# Storing temperature data given a certain hour (Arrays

Tags: arrays

How would you go about storing data of temperature given a certain hour? I understand it uses an array but i have no clue how to approach the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a convention that array index is the hour
`temp[0] = 34`  - this means that at midnight it is 34 degrees
`temp[1] = 36`  - this means that at 1 in the night it is 36 degrees
and so on.

```
float[] temp = new float[24];
```